# How to calculate the degrees of freedom, constraints and the generalized coordinates in this dynamic system

Tags: applied-mechanics, dynamics, mathematics, kinematics

The rope lengths are taken to be constant.

**Solution:**
$N$ particles with $k$ constraints.
. Then the Degree of Freedom (DOF) is $3N-k$.

In Figure 1, we have two particles $m_1$ and $m_2$, so $N=2$. But what I don't understand is how to find the constraints in Figure 1, Generalized Coordinates and Virtual Work.

Help would be appreciated.[image: The rope lengths are taken to be constant.]

Comment: If I understand correctly the diagram, then the system has only 1 degree of freedom. Which is the movement of the 2-mass system. Since they don't move independently. The constraint is that the position of mass 2 depends on the position of mass 1.